# Ubuntu-Debian boot with black screen with horizontal colored little lines

Tags: debian, ubuntu, boot

I try to install either Ubuntu or Debian on an hp laptop

hp 2000 notebook
with cpu:
amd e1 1500 apu with Radeon (tm) HD

When I put the bootable stick (made with rufus) I see a black screen with horizontal colored little lines going down, same thing happens both with Ubuntu and Debian stick...
Both sticks are booting and leading to the first screen on an other older laptop I have.
It seems it's a graphics card problem from what have I have read, but in the bios of this laptop doesn't have any graphic card options

Any ideas what's happening?
Or is it possible the laptop to have a broken graphics unit and be able to display bios and console letters in general but nothing else?

Thanks

Comment: Try installing Fedora 32 - it contains a much fresher kernel than those two.

Comment: guys thanks for the answers but you both suggest to download an othe iso and i have exhausted my limited data for this month :/